# $ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2n(1-e^{\pi}(-1)^{n})}{(n^{2}+1)\pi} \sin(nx), \quad -\pi<x<\pi$ convergent uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{2n(1-e^{\pi}(-1)^{n})}{(n^{2}+1)\pi} \sin(nx)$$
converge uniformly on $]-\pi,\pi[$ ?

How can I analyze it using Weierstrass M-test?

I know that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}
\frac{2n-2ne^{\pi}(-1)^{n}}{(n^{2}+1)\pi}=0$$ but I can't conclude with that uniform convergence from this information.

Comment: I don't see how the $M$-test can apply.  If $x=\frac\pi2$ and $n$ is odd then $$\left\lvert \frac{2n(1-e^{\pi}(-1)^{n})}{(n^{2}+1)\pi} \sin(nx)\right\rvert>\frac n{n^2+1}$$ and the $M$-test fails.

Comment: how do you get inequality? I can't deduce it.

Comment: When $x=\frac\pi2,$ and $n$ is odd, $|\sin(nx)|=1$ and $(-1)^n=-1$ so the whole expression becomes $\frac{2(1+e^\pi)}{\pi}\frac n{n^2+1}$